# Issue with If Check in C#

Tags: c#, .net

OK, So here is my if check, no matter how I've tried it, it's not going through properly, it keeps stopping.

```
DateTime now = new DateTime();
string s = "Everyday";
string currentTime = now.ToString("HH:mm");
string remDate = "21:00"; //set to a minute or two i the future
string CurrentDay = "Sunday";

if ((s.ToUpper() == "WORKDAYS") ||(s.ToUpper() == "EVERYDAY" || s.ToUpper() == CurrentDay.ToUpper()) 
&& ((currentTime == remDate) && (s.ToUpper() != "SUNDAY") && (s.ToUpper() != "SATURDAY")))
{
     MessageBox.Show("Success!!!!");
}
```

So when it hits the if check, it stops, never gets to the message box. No matter what order I've tried the checks it's not working, been staring at this for a while, thought someone out there could either show me a better way, or see what I'm missing.

Comment: It might help to state in English what your if test should do.

Comment: how could `(currentTime == remDate)` ever pass unless you are lucky at guessing what time it will be when you run the code and putting that time in as `remDate` ahead of time?

Comment: Seems like a really complex conditional.  I don't know if you are intending to 'and' the clause that checks (currentTime == remDate).  What do you actually want to accomplish?

Comment: @Nebseb - You can fix typos in your question by editing the question.

Answer (score 3):

Cause it will work only at 21:00

UPD:
Sorry, it was mistake. Real reason in first line
You have to write `DateTime now = DateTime.Now;`

Answer (score 0):

If you see that your **s is Everyday**, hence the first condition is met. But you have AND condition with

`(currentTime == remDate) && (s.ToUpper() != "SUNDAY") && (s.ToUpper() != "SATURDAY")`

which will only be true when time is **21:00**

which isn't true at this time. Hence the condition is failed.

Answer (score 0):

Lets start by making your code more readable, which also helps show your `||` and `&&` issues.

```
DateTime now = new DateTime();
string s = "Everyday";
string currentTime = now.ToString("HH:mm");
string remDate = "21:00"; //set to a minute or two i the future
string CurrentDay = "Sunday";

if (
    // condition 1
    (s.ToUpper() == "WORKDAYS") 
    // condition 2
    || (
        s.ToUpper() == "EVERYDAY" 
        || s.ToUpper() == CurrentDay.ToUpper()
    ) 
    // condition 3
    && (
        // condition 3.1
        (currentTime == remDate) 
        && (s.ToUpper() != "SUNDAY") 
        && (s.ToUpper() != "SATURDAY")
    )
)
{
    // I'm using LINQPad, so I just output this to the results
    "Success!!!!".Dump();
}
```

One issue is condition 3.1: `(currentTime == remDate)`. Given the sample input provided this has to be true, so your message box will only display when the time is 21:00.

Another issue is that condition 2 and condition 3 will (because they are joined with `&&`) be treated as a group. Is this what you really meant?

The logic of this `if` statement is hard to follow and the grouping or/and expressions add to the confusion.

Try writing the conditions out in english, maybe as a bullet list, and see if the mistake doesn't become obvious to you.

Answer (score 0):

Here I assume that your variable `CurrentDay` is equal to `DayOfWeek.Monday.ToString().ToUpper()`.

according to your statement, it looks like

```
if(false || true && false)
```

Because `(s.ToUpper() == "WORKDAYS")` is always false, until you change `s`.
and `(s.ToUpper() == "EVERYDAY" || s.ToUpper() == CurrentDay.ToUpper())` is always true until you change s
and `((currentTime == remDate) && (s.ToUpper() != "SUNDAY") && (s.ToUpper() != "SATURDAY") 
&& (CurrentDay == s))` is always false, because `(CurrentDay == s)` is false.

Hence if statement is always false, then `MessageBox.Show("Success!!!!");` cannot be executed..

Answer (score 0):

I got it working. I should have explained it better, what I was trying to do is have it check the time of day and then check the day, and then have an alert pop up, the values come from the end user, stored in a sqlite db.

The problem was the grouping and the order and I had a duplicate check in my code.

what i ended up with was:

```
if ((s.ToUpper() == "WORKDAYS") || (s.ToUpper() == "EVERYDAY" || s.ToUpper() == CurrentDay.ToUpper())
&& ((currentTime == remDate) && (s.ToUpper() != "SUNDAY") && (s.ToUpper() != "SATURDAY")))
{
}
```

I had it do all my OR checks first, then had it pull in the last group of AND's and then i grouped them, this works for me and does the job.

I'm writing my own reminder application and this was my weekday check that i implemented. Probably a better way to do it, but this was what i came up with.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

replace:

```
string currentTime = now.ToString("HH:mm");
```

and

`(currentTime == remDate)`

by this:

```
DateTime currentTime = DateTime.Now
```

and

```
(currentTime.ToString("HH:mm") == remDate)
```